# How to get QTableWidget + QComboBox together and how to access perticular row if value is changed from QComboBox of same row

Tags: qt, qt5, qtablewidget, qcombobox, qtwidgets

I am stucked at the combination of  QTableWidget + QComboBox.

[image: My expected output something like this ...]

As showing in the screenshot, what I want is that, whenever I want insert new item inside table after hitting **ADD** button, **new row should be inserted into the table** and at the end I want **Drop Down box with text of Allow and Block.**

```
webFilterCat = new QTableWidget(0);
webFilterCat -> verticalHeader()->setDefaultSectionSize(15);
webFilterCat -> setMaximumWidth(310);
webFilterCat -> setMinimumWidth(310);
webFilterCat -> setMaximumHeight(170);
webFilterCat -> setMinimumHeight(170);
/* Set Row and Column Count*/
//webFilterCat->setRowCount(10);
webFilterCat->setColumnCount(3);

/* Table Header */
tableHeader<<"Category"<<"Status"<<"Action";
webFilterCat -> setHorizontalHeaderLabels(tableHeader);
webFilterCat -> horizontalHeader()->setDefaultSectionSize(100);

// ------ Insert Data -------
webFilterCat->insertRow ( webFilterCat->rowCount() );
webFilterCat->setItem(( webFilterCat->rowCount() -1 ), 0, new QTableWidgetItem(extName));
webFilterCat -> setItem(( webFilterCat->rowCount() -1 ), 1, new QTableWidgetItem("Block"));
webFilterCat -> setCellWidget ( ( webFilterCat->rowCount() -1 ), 2, new QComboBox( webFilterCat ) );
```

I am getting QComboBox at every row after adding item into table but I cant set label (i.e. Allow or Block) to QComboBox and How to access that perticular row after value is changed in QComboBox.

I am using **qt 4.2** and compiling code using **linux terminal**.

**In short not using qt creator , using command line qt.**

Comment: You might store some sort of mapping between row a combo box pointers and the corresponding row number, like: `std::map<QComboBox *, int>`. Once a combo box item is activated, you can know which row it was for.

Comment: @vahancho No. Unfortunately that i cant use. Because sometimes user can delete a row so that logic will fail here. First suggest how to insert label in QComboBox

Comment: Is `QDataWidgetMapper` not what you are looking for?

Comment: Hello @MasterAler I am newbie to QT. I dont know QDataWidgetMapper. I just want to do my tast\k by hook or by cook. 
I am getting QComboBox at every row after adding item into table but I cant set label (i.e. Allow or Block) to QComboBox and How to access that perticular row after value is changed in QComboBox .
Tell me how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for my problem .

```
webFilterCat = new QTableWidget(0);
webFilterCat -> verticalHeader()->setDefaultSectionSize(15);
webFilterCat -> setMaximumWidth(310);
webFilterCat -> setMinimumWidth(310);
webFilterCat -> setMaximumHeight(170);
webFilterCat -> setMinimumHeight(170);
/* Set Row and Column Count*/
//webFilterCat->setRowCount(10);
webFilterCat->setColumnCount(3);

/* Table Header */
tableHeader<<"Category"<<"Status"<<"Action";
webFilterCat -> setHorizontalHeaderLabels(tableHeader);
webFilterCat -> horizontalHeader()->setDefaultSectionSize(100);

for(int i=0; i<row_count; i++){
    // ------ Insert Data -------
    webFilterCat->insertRow ( webFilterCat->rowCount() );
    webFilterCat->setItem(( webFilterCat->rowCount() -1 ), 0, new QTableWidgetItem(extName));
    webFilterCat -> setItem(( webFilterCat->rowCount() -1 ), 1, new QTableWidgetItem("Block"));
    /*webFilterCat -> setCellWidget ( ( webFilterCat->rowCount() -1 ), 2, new QComboBox( webFilterCat ) );*/

    cmbCatAllowOrBlock = new QComboBox ( 0 );

    cmbCatAllowOrBlock -> setFixedSize ( 80, 20 ); // 75, 20
    cmbCatAllowOrBlock -> addItem ( "Allow" );
    cmbCatAllowOrBlock -> addItem ( "Block" );
    cmbCatAllowOrBlock -> setCurrentIndex( 0 );

    webFilterCat -> setCellWidget ( ( webFilterCat->rowCount() -1 ), 2, cmbCatAllowOrBlock );
}
```

I got the solution what I need as shown below.

[image]

and got solution for this problem as well

> How to access that perticular row after value is changed in QComboBox ?

What I did, at the time of read perticular QComboBox of perticular row. I will not try to read perticular QComboBox of perticular row. I only need the changed state of the QComboBox, so I will read whole table and compare with previous one and able to find the change.

So, how to read QComboBox row by row is

```
for(int i=0;i<(webFilterCat->rowCount() -1);i++){
       QComboBox* combo=(QComboBox*) webFilterCat -> cellWidget(i, 2);
       qDebug() <<  combo -> currentText();
}
```